# How to Determine How many cycles it would take to get a given value to 0 by decreasing it by a given amount

Tags: for-loop, casting, output

This is my problem, i need to take double onHand and reduce it by the double consume, then determine how many cycles it would take to reach 0. then use Math.Round 3 to round it to 3 decimal points.

```
        public static int Test4(double onHand, double consume)
        {
            int answer = 1;
            for (int i = (int)(consume); i > onHand; i--)
            {
                answer -= (int)onHand;
            }
            return answer;
        }
```

I tried creating multiple variables like introducing decimals, casting the doubles into floats and ints but i can only get to the point where my answer outputs the int of the onHand.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce"? Substract double from onHand? Can you add a simple example with the result? Also, how do you know it will reach exactly 0?

Comment: so the starting value is onHand, the number is a random decimal like 3.02, and the amount I have to reduce it by, consume is also a random decimal like 0.24. Then i have to figure out how many cycles it will take consume (random example 0.24) to reduce onHand (random example 3.02) to get to or below 0.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the meaning of "reduce", if you mean substract like: 3.02 - 0.24 = 2.78 and repeat like 2.54, 2.3, 2.06, 1.82, etc etc and count how many loops it will take, then you can just divide the numbers. 3.02/0.24=12.583. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes exactly, then my answer has to be the number of times it goes through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to make a division.

Assuming `onHand` is 3.02 and `consume` is 0.24, you divide them like `onHand / consume` and that will result in 12.583333. You will have to ceil or round-up the value (13). That is the number of times it'll go trough the loop to reach or pass 0.

Example

```
public static int Test4(double onHand, double consume)
{
    double answer = (decimal)onHand / (decimal)consume;
    return (int) Math.Ceiling(answer);
}
```

I'm no expert on C# so I don't know if the casting is neccesary.

Comment: Thank you so much, just that tidbit got me to figure out the correct coding sequence i needed.

Comment: It made me cast both decimals as double, also it gave me the answers rounded up to the next whole integer which sends a 0 for the score. I think you are right but they want it rounded down to the integer not up since 6.6 days would not be 7 days it would be 6 days to run out of the onHand. the one I posted got me the right answer but the one you did makes sense because you can hit negative for yours, on mine you can't consume more than what is available.

Comment: @MiguelFreytes-Calderon in that case, use `Math.Floor` instead of `Math.Ceiling`, that should round down the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int Test4(double onHand, double consume)
{
  int answer = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < consume; i++)
  {
    answer = (int)((decimal)onHand / (decimal)consume);
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: This allowed me to input the random double for onHand, which I cast as a decimal and divided it by consume, which I also cast as a decimal, then to allow them to divide the program forced me to do a second casting for int and my answer is the number of times consume divided into onhand as an Integer.

Comment: You don't the for loop to get that answer. Also, you're dividing the same numbers again and again. I'll update my answer so you can see the correct code.